# Programmatically create class attributes for declarative defined classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is for python 3 (latest). I know that I can do:

```
class Foo:
    id = some_method_defining_id()
```

Or

```
class Foo:
     (id, uuid) = some_method_defining_id_and_uuid()
```

I would like to have a method that can return multiple class attributes whose names I do not know:

```
class Foo:
    **some_method_defining_multiple_unknown_attributes() # returns a dict
```

I do know that I can define Foo programmatically using the `type`. I also know I can add the attributes after the class definition.

Comment: I fail to see why you'd want to abuse the language that way, but you could easily do something like that in a metaclass or in a class decorator, whichever type abuse you prefer ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** Don't try this <s>at home</s> at work. It is ugly.

I'll give you three ways to do it.

### A Class Decorator

```
def get_me_some_attributes():
    return {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

def add_attributes_to_class(attributes):
    def decorate_class(cls):
        for name, value in attributes.items():
            setattr(cls, name, value)
    return cls
return decorate_class


@add_attributes_to_class(get_me_some_attributes())
class A:
    pass
```

Test it:

```
>>> A.a
1
>>> A.b
2
```

### A Direct Call of the Metaclass Constructor

```
>>> B = type('B', (object,), get_me_some_attributes())
>>> B
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> B.a
1
>>> B.b
2
>>>
```

### A Custom Metaclass

```
class MySpecialMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        SPECIAL_STUFF = namespace.pop('SPECIAL_STUFF', {})
        namespace.update(SPECIAL_STUFF)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)

class C(metaclass=MySpecialMeta):
    SPECIAL_STUFF = get_me_some_attributes()
```

Test it:

```
>>> C
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> C.a
1
>>> C.b
2
```